# Converting excel to pdf issue in converting third column

Tags: python, pdf-generation

i want to convert my excel file into pdf but im getting issue while converting third column 3rd columns in not properly alling please help me to solve that problem

expected result

index column first name last name  gender

1                a            b       f

2                dd            gg      m

actual

index first name last name

1      a            Gender

2```   dd             gg

import pandas as pd

from fpdf import FPDF

df_2 = pd.read_excel('exceltopdf.xlsx')

pdf = FPDF()

pdf.add_page()

pdf.set_xy(0, 0)

pdf.set_font('arial', 'B', 14)

pdf.cell(60)

pdf.cell(70, 10, 'Writing a PDF from python', 0, 4, 'C')

pdf.cell(-40)

pdf.cell(50, 10, 'Index Column', 1, 0, 'C')

pdf.cell(40, 10, 'First Name', 1, 0, 'C')

pdf.cell(40, 10, 'Last Name', 1, 2, 'C')

pdf.cell(40, 10, 'Gender', 1, 3, 'C')

pdf.cell(-90)

pdf.set_font('arial', '', 12)

for i in range(0, len(df_2)-1):

```
col_ind = str(i)

col_a = str(df_2['First Name'].ix[i])

col_b = str(df_2['Last Name'].ix[i])

col_c = str(df_2['Gender'].ix[i])

pdf.cell(50, 10, '%s' % (col_ind), 1, 0, 'C')

pdf.cell(40, 10, '%s' % (col_a), 0, 0, 'C')

pdf.cell(40, 10, '%s' % (col_b), 0, 2, 'C')

pdf.cell(40, 10, '%s' % (col_c), 0, 4, 'C')

pdf.cell(-90)
```

```
pdf.output('test.pdf', 'F')
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting on this post. It's impossible to tell what your issue is.

Comment: please it now i think its good

Comment: Most of the code still isn't formatted as code, and your example of your expected result also isn't formatted in a way that makes it obvious what you're trying to achieve.